# Set number limit of items in isotope filtering

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-isotope

This is my script isotope :

```js
//isotope : filtering
jQuery(function($) {
// init Isotope
    var $grid = $('.grid_posts').isotope({
        // options
        itemSelector: '.grid_posts-item',
        layoutMode: 'fitRows',
    });

// filter items on button click
    $('.filter-button-group').on('click', '.filter-ecm', function () {
        var filterValue = $(this).attr('data-filter');
        $grid.isotope({filter: filterValue});
    });

//change class on items selected
    $('.button-group').each( function( i, buttonGroup ) {
        var $buttonGroup = $( buttonGroup );
        $buttonGroup.on( 'click', '.filter-ecm', function() {
            $buttonGroup.find('.is-checked').removeClass('is-checked');
            $( this ).addClass('is-checked');
        });
    });
});
```

This code works and filter my articles well. But I want to display just the 6 first articles not all the articles. How can I limit the number of items ?

Here there is an example of my problem : https://codepen.io/zazzou/pen/NWgqVqg
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a selector which specifies the maximum number of elements you wish to "grab" before passing it to $grid.isotope

For example:

```
var limiter = ':nth-child(-n+6)',
    filterValue = $(this).attr('data-filter' + limiter);

    $grid.isotope({filter: filterValue});
```

As long as you can confirm the CSS selector is grabbing the first N values (in your case 6) your filter will only consider an array of that length

Comment: It does not work... When I click on the filters nothing happen and I have still all my articles displaying on my page...

Comment: @chtouk are you able to grab the element(s) via jquery prior to using `isotope`? If yes then it is a matter of ensuring `isotope` is filtering correctly

Comment: I add a link to codepen because it is more easier to see what is my problem.

Comment: sorry don't understand how to do that. Can you explain ?

Comment: in your web browser console, you can use jquery like this to grab the elements: `$('button-group:nth-child(-n+6)')` you can break the CSS selector down to make it simpler, that should return the top 6 in your button group, if that does not work then you get an empy array which you cannot filter